# Form validation is not working

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, prototype-js

I have looked at various tutorials and they all say that to get form validation working in magento is as simple as setting the correct class in the input boxes and adding the form name to the VarienForm() function.

I am not getting anything with this method:

```
<form name="regform" id="regform" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('*/*/save') ?>" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?>
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <label class="required" class="required" class="required" for="first name"><?php echo $this->__('First name') ?><span>*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name" value="<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('f_name') ?>" class="input-text required-entry">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <label for="last name"><?php echo $this->__('Last Name') ?><span>*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="l_name" id="l_name" value="<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('l_name') ?>" class="input-text required-entry">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var dataForm = new VarienForm('regform', true);
        //]]
</script>
```

My javascript is very weak, so I have been blindly following tutorials, I have gone taken some time to learn more Javascript but my limited time spent understanding the language leaves me thinking this should work. Where am I going wrong?

===EDIT===

In the console, I get the following message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent' prototype.js:5653
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent' prototype.js:5653
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent' prototype.js:5653
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent' prototype.js:5734
```

Comment: not working? are you getting any javascript error? pls check for any in your browser's developer tool.

Comment: sorry, I forgot about the console being able to give me more detailed information, I will update my question

Comment: do you use jQuery in your site?

Comment: It's early enough to change to jquery, but I thought it would be a good idea to try and get used to using what comes shipped with Magento to reduce extra load on each page

Comment: no, I don't recommend jQuery, Magento form validation is simple and elegant. I asked you, if you use jQuery library in your website, because this kind of error occurs due to jQuery and prototype conflict.

Comment: it seems that I had put jquery in when I first started to learn Magento, using the local.xml. I have now got rid of that and it works perfectly apart from on the drop down menu's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs because of the conflict between prototype and jQuery libraries. To solve this, add `jQuery.noConflict();` at the end of jQuery library.

This will solve the conflict.